# using class object to initialize variable from 1 package to another but it is not accessable in java

Tags: java

my class.java content

```
package pkg1;
import pkg2.*;
public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        student stu = new student();
        stu.getName("go");
    }
}
```

---

```
contentof student.java

package pkg2;
public class student {
    public int id;
    String name; 
    int rollno;
    int age;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to initialize variable of student.java of pkg 2 from myclass.java 
 but its showing field is not visible  i have imported contents of pkg2 in pkg1 myclass.java and also have declared the member function of student.java as public

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indent your code so it is readable. Please also follow the Java naming convention and name classes using a capital first letter.

Comment: what do you want to do? provide some input and output @user

Comment: How can you pass the argument to `getName()`? In definition, it does not takes any argument.

Answer (score 0):

How did you know it is not accessible? Did you encounter any error statement saying this? Take this as a rule of thumb to read the errors accurately before jumping to conclusions.

Try putting this in you main function.

```
student stu = new student();
stu.setName("go");
System.out.println(stu.getname());
```

Set the name using the setter first. Only then will you be able to get the name via the getter.
BTW you need to learn a lot of coding [Java conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/codeconvtoc-136057.html) as well. Like classnames should be starting with a capital. student -> Student.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking here, but first as pointed out by several of the comments to your question you cannot pass any arguments to `getName()` as it doesn't take any arguments. Secondly, as also pointed out in the comments, please conform to the Java naming convention.

```java
package pkg1;

import pkg2.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student stu = new Student();
        stu.setName("go");
        //Verify the name's been set
        System.out.println(stu.getName());
    }
}
```

```java
package pkg2;

public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int rollno;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```